# Как подгружаются CSS к таблице

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть несколько CSS файлов, которые относятся к разным html страницам. CSS подгружается, только к нужным классам, которые есть в документе или пока не загрузятся все?

Comment: Все подгружаются... Если они подключены...

Comment: Обычно на страницу подключается файл со стилями. Если файл стилей подключен в начале документа, то элементы отрисовываются сразу с применением правил, указанных в файле стилей. Если стили подключены внизу, то правила могут применяться с задержкой.